# Is dedicated gateway a need for marketplace projects?

Tags: infura, ipfs, alchemy, pinata

I am developing an NFT marketplace. It has a section showing **images of NFT**s ( NFTCards with some information ) of a specific contract address. Since the number of minted NFTs by the contract is high, the page takes too long to load pictures!

I looked up the internet for a solution to decrease this load time, which is more caused by the large size of the nft pictures ( IPFS pinned files ).

There is a service called "**Dedicated Gateway**" by IPFS Pinning services like **Infura**.

Now here is my question:

- Does using a dedicated gateway significantly increase the speed of loading nft images in my Dapp? If yes, how it is done?

Comment: How do you currently load your images? Do you just try to load the URL that the smart contract gives you? And if it sends you an `ipfs://` what do you use to load that?

Comment: I use alchemy SDK to fetch an array of the one's NFTs, then render media[0].gateway of each token within a <img>

Answer (score 0):

Using a dedicated gateway greatly increases the speed of IPFS retrieval depending on the service. They are usually put together with a large network of nodes that are peered with other nodes from other services instead of just one node that is searching for the content. As the name designates, instead of being shared by millions of people like a public gateway, dedicated gateways are like a highway where only you can use it (if thats how you want it to be set). Speeds are also achieved by using a CDN cache layer on both the node level and gateway level to help improve subsequent retrievals. You can read more about them [here](https://docs.pinata.cloud/docs/dedicated-ipfs-gateways)